# Trouble Understanding Code to Export Excel Spreadsheet from HTML

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, webforms

I have been asked to make changes to an ASP.NET WebForms application written in VB (I normally use C#).

One task is to try and fix an Excel download. The client reported that he gets an error about the spreadsheet being corrupt when he attempts to open it in Excel.

The code that exports the Excel download appears in the Load event of a dedicated ASPX page. And looks something like this:

```
Dim mytable As New HtmlTable
mytable = [Populate HTML Table Here]

mytable = returnclass.displaytable
mytable.Border = 1
mytable.BorderColor = "#CCCCCC"

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = True

Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"">")
Response.Write("<head>")
Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>")
Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook>")
Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets>")
Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet>")
Response.Write("<x:Name>" & worksheetTitle & "</x:Name>")
Response.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions>")
Response.Write("<x:Print>")
Response.Write("<x:ValidPrinterInfo/>")
Response.Write("</x:Print>")
Response.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions>")
Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet>")
Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets>")
Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook>")
Response.Write("</xml>")
Response.Write("<![endif]--> ")
Response.Write("</head>")
Response.Write("<body>")

HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=hhexport.xls ")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = ""

'ouput table to html so excel can interperet.
Me.EnableViewState = False
Dim stringWriter As New System.IO.StringWriter()
Dim htmlWriter As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter)
mytable.RenderControl(htmlWriter)

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString)
```

I really don't understand what this is trying to do.

Questions:

1. The code produces a regular ASP.NET `HtmlTable` and assigns it to `mytable`. On what planet can Excel open HTML?
2. I'm really kind of loss by the XML in general here, and by the `<!--[if gte mso 9]` comment. Can anyone help me understand what is going on here.

The result appears valid but I'm just not familiar with what the intent is here. Any tips appreciated.

**EDIT**

On further testing, the problem seems related to the extension given to the file (xls). The current version of Excel will go ahead and load the file if I indicate that. But all formatting is lost. Any suggestions on what type of file this would be?

**EDIT**

And it looks like the original author got the idea from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1573064.aspx), although that page doesn't really describe what is happening.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for everyone's response. I will credit those replies according to how they addressed the questions above. However, for my purposes the code appears to have worked all along. It just appears that newer versions of Excel now warn the user that an XLS file that contains HTML is a file of a different type than suggested by the file extension. And it appears there is nothing that can be done about this except for exporting using CSV, OpenXML or some other approach. I found more details in [this blog](http://devblog.grinn.net/2008/06/file-you-are-trying-to-open-is-in.html).

Comment: Yeah, Excel will natively open HTML tables as if they were Excel cells.  All of the Excel snippets I've seen have never included the part with `<html xmlns:x=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"">`.    I'd just implement the method found here: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/c-sharp/asp-net-export-to-excel-and-word-using-vb-net-and-c/

Comment: Ugh! Thanks but sheesh, that site has horrible formatting of code. Makes it difficult to see what is what.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the best formatting, but it was the first one that had the code I'm familiar using.

Comment: Hmmm, that seems to give me exactly the same result. Excel reports that the file is in a different format than specified by the file extension.

Comment: But it still opens, right?  That's always happened for me with this method.

Comment: Yes, it seems that this code may have actually worked all along. But it is unsettling to the client and his customers to have an error message popping up.

Comment: Well, explain to them that it's Excel being extra careful, and not something you can control.  Put the blame on Excel and tell them any other way is going to cost time and money, and I think they'll find a way to get over being afraid of a popup error.

Comment: Yes, I've reported back. But you don't always have the ability to explain to all of your customers and this can make them uneasy. I have suggested CSV and OpenXML as possible alternatives.

Comment: Yeah, I've had the same trouble (people really don't like that error) - I think CSV is a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code basically wraps an HTML table in some special XML tags that relate to Excel (defining a Workbook and Worksheets, etc).  This is supposed to allow the output to be opened by either Excel or a browser.

To answer your questions:

1. *The code produces a regular ASP.NET HtmlTable and assigns it to mytable. On what planet can Excel open HTML?*  Actually, that's a feature of Excel.  You can use a special combination of XML and HTML tags to create files that are open-able on the web and in Excel.  See this MSDN article: [How to format an Excel workbook while streaming MIME content](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271572)
2. *I'm really kind of loss by the XML in general here, and by the `<!--[if gte mso 9]` comment. Can anyone help me understand what is going on here.*  That specific comment is checking for the availability of MS Excel (whether it's being opened by Excel or a browser), I believe.  The XML is specific tags that have special meaning in MS Excel.  There's a reference you can download here: [Microsoft® Office HTML and XML Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx)

I found this article on C# Corner to be pretty helpful in understanding this type of code: [Creating a Dynamic Excel Using HTML](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaushikborah28/79Nick08302007171404PM/79Nick.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Excel has been able to read HTML for quite a while. This particular approach is pretty common, but it's definitely not best practice.

The important part of this logic is here:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=hhexport.xls ")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = ""

'ouput table to html so excel can interperet.
Me.EnableViewState = False
Dim stringWriter As New System.IO.StringWriter()
Dim htmlWriter As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter)    
mytable.RenderControl(htmlWriter)

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString)
```

The `Response.Write` logic is just being used to control the workbook and worksheet that gets outputted. If that logic was not there, the file would open with three worksheets similar to a new Excel workbook.